# Android, setSelected() and state_selected

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

I'm having trouble with `View.setSelected()`. `Views` are flagged as selected -- `TextViews`, for example, change their font color -- but my background selectors don't seem to register the change.

Example selector:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

    <item android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ff8600" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

I'm not even sure which kind of context information would be useful. The views are children of a LinearLayout, and I'm programatically setting the selected state inside a touch event. As I said, it *does* seem to work, since the font color goes from white to gray, but the background stays the same.

**Edit**: I checked for silly mistakes before posting :P. The answer is not "add the android:background attribute".

Comment: I dont know whether or not the order of items matters in selector xmls, but where ever I have seen it, the default item is always at the bottom in the items list.

Comment: You, sir, are a genius. Apparently, it tries to match the states in order. Write the answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The order of items matters in selector xmls, the default item should always be at the bottom in the items list.

Comment: Holy crap, I was fighting this for an hour or two. Thanks, you've done me a great service.

Comment: thanks, I also fought this problem for quite some while... This is ridiculous

Answer (score 8):

not only the selected state order is important, even the order of all states is important. In my case, I added `state_pressed` as first and my `state_selected` doesn´t work. So I changed the order like this, and then it worked:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item 
    android:state_selected="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/chooser_normal"></item>
<item 
    android:state_selected="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/chooser_pressed"></item>
<item 
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/chooser_pressed"></item>
<item 
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/chooser_normal"></item>
 </selector>
```

### EDIT

I faced now also the problem, if I press the button, it will be in the selected-state but not in pressed-state. So, the solution must be, to order the states like this and additional, it´s a good practise to add a default button look:

First, set the selected state and after this, set the same as pressed state alternately. (For now, stackoverflow isn´t showing my edit completely, don´t know why, just be patient please).

Answer (score 0):

It's not obvious why, but I think this might work (notice the addition of state_selected="false"):

```
<item android:state_selected="false" android:drawable="@android:color/transparent" />

<item android:state_selected="true">
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#ff8600" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

I hope that's helpful.